# I downloaded ubuntu 15.04 from canonical's website but wubi is ignoring that file and downloading ubuntu 14.10 x64 amd

Tags: wubi

I downloaded ubuntu 15.04 from canonical's website but wubi is ignoring that file and downloading ubuntu 14.10 x64 amd.but not my processor neither my motherboard are from amd.help me.it's urgent.

Comment: If your processor is 64bit, and (not arm) then you can probably use the AMD64 iso. AMD got to put their name on the 64bit support, as they wrote the support for it. However it works on most 64bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to install from a Live USB or from a CD. A live USB disk can be created easily with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html). WUBI is no longer supported. You can read more about this here:

[Official Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766)

Another good run-down is located [here](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com).

If you need help with the Ubuntu installation process then [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) is a good starting place and we can then help with more specific questions if needed. Also, as I've been asked before, I have no idea why WUBI is still included when it doesn't usually work and is no longer officially supported.

Comment: not working. when i boot using unetbootin.the pc says that press any key to boot from usb.i pressed enter.then it shows that it doesn't contain an operating system.help me

Comment: As a lark, try burning it (as an image - don't just copy it) to CD/DVD. If you need help with that then see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto for more information.

Comment: please give a complete guide to install ubuntu 15.04 using pendrive it is urgent.My dvd writer has broken down.I am a beginner of ubuntu.never used it.

Comment: This really belongs as a new question - the question you asked was answered, don't use WUBI. But, format  your drive with FAT32, for some reason this works best for me. Then, using the .ISO file that you've downloaded, use unetbootin and burn that image to the flash drive you're using. You will need to first completely format the drive so if you have important information back it up. Use FAT32, as mentioned, and let us know if it works. You may wish to also go back and edit your original question to add your new problems. This is for replies and whatnot - not really for 'chatting' type stuff.